# Rotate around the center of a CCLabelTTF as achnor point

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to rotate a CCLabelTTF around it's center.

But it doesn't look like it. It does look more like a rotation at the bottom of the CCLabelTTF.

Code:

```
CCLabelTTF *aLabel ... init/addChild and so on

CCRotateBy *rotateLabelA = [[CCRotateBy alloc] initWithDuration:0.5f angle:-60.0f];

aLabel.string = @"0";
aLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
[aLabel runAction:rotateLabelA];
```

How to rotate a letter around its visible center, if it is a CCLabelTTF?

I was able to make the boundary box of a `CCLabelTTF` visible:

[image: cclabelttfboundingbox]

As seen in the image, the bounding box is much bigger. But there isn't a formula to determine the middle of the letter.

Comment: May be show us how do you create your CCRotate action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to find the middle point of an `CCLabelTTF`:

```
    float fontSize = bLabel.fontSize; // actual Font size in pixels
    float labelHeight = bLabel.contentSize.height; // actual label height ( the same as boundingBox.size.height )
    float offset = labelHeight - fontSize; // the free room under the font
    float halfFontSize = fontSize / 2;
    float percentMiddleOfFont = (halfFontSize + offset) / labelHeight;

    bLabel.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, percentMiddleOfFont);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `anchorPoint = cpp(0.5f,0.5f)` to some ccNode object, it will rotate around its center, which is calculated using boundingBox property.

The problem is the label's boundingBox.size.height differs with it's actual height. That is why it rotates not around the center.

I am not sure in such a manual solution, but it worked for me someday.

```
    CCLabelTTF *label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Marker Felt"fontSize:24];
    label.position = ccp(winSize.width /2.0f, winSize.height / 2.0f);

    float fontSize = label.fontSize; // actual Font size
    float labelHeight = label.contentSize.height; // actual label height ( the same as boundingBox.size.height
    float offset = (labelHeight - fontSize - (labelHeight - fontSize) / 2.0f) / labelHeight / 2.0f;
    label.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f + offset);

    [layer addChild:label];
    [label runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:10.0f angle:-360]];
```

Comment: It looks better than anchorPoint 0.5, 0.5 but it isn't the center. I will try to understand what you did, maybe I can find out what I need.